# Creating a basic menu, why can't I get this right? -Java

Tags: java, menu

I'm taking an Intro to Java class, and I haven't been having any trouble until now. I don't know if I'm just being a fool and the answer is simple but here goes.

I need to create a simple menu. I prompt the user, and then they enter an integer to choose one option. But there also needs to be an option to type "X" and exit the program.

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Welcome to the Math Study Guide!");
    System.out.println("Which arithmetic table would you like to use?");
    System.out.println("1) Addition");
    System.out.println("2) Subtraction");
    System.out.println("3) Multiplication");
    System.out.println("4) Division");
    System.out.println("X) Exit the program");
    int input = in.nextInt();


    if (input <= 5 )
        {if (input == 1){System.out.println("Addition");}
        {if (input == 2){System.out.println("Subtraction");}
        {if (input == 3){System.out.println("Multiplication");}
        {if (input == 4){System.out.println("Division");}

    else {System.out.println("You have exited");}
```

Testing it, whenever I type "X" it shuts down everything and doesn't tell me I've exited. Is there a general input I can use where you can enter either an int or a String?

Comment: yes. You need to not use `nextInt` but rather take in a `char` and cast to `int`. You have it already what is wrong, you know that it's choking on `X` in `nextInt`.

Comment: You could use just the ```next()``` method which returns a string, then compare input to '1', '2' etc. Also advised to use ```switch``` case instead of the if statements.

Comment: @ShawnMehan I'm not quite sure what you mean by casting it into int, could you elaborate?

Comment: @Siddhartha I've tried that but it keeps telling me next() isn't a valid thing I can do.

Comment: @Brandon I just tried it, and it's working for me: ```String input = in.next();```

Comment: String input = in.next();
  
  if ( input == "1"){System.out.println("Addition");}
  else if ( input == "2"){System.out.println("Subtraction");}
  else if ( input == "3"){System.out.println("Multiplication");}
  else if ( input == "4"){System.out.println("Division");}
  else if ( input == "X"){System.out.println("You exited");} @Siddhartha this isn't even reading as me inputting anything when I type, why is that?

Comment: What do you mean it's not reading? Does it not wait for you to input a character? Also, now that you're working with ```String```, you need to use the equals method: ```input.equals("X")```

Answer (score 0):

As already stated in some comments, your probleme is the data-type. If someone enters 'X' in the program, it is expected to be an integer value, which it is not.

To get your Program working you need to alter your datatype from int to String

```
String input = in.next();
```

this will get you the input.

Now make a switch/case instead of your if-statements

```
switch (input) {
    case "1" : System.out.println("Addition");
    break;
    case "2" : System.out.println("Subtraction");
    break;
    deafult: System.out.println("You have exited the program");
    break;
}
```

If you are not familiar with the switch/case statement: case "1" checks if input equals "1". If true it prints out "Addition", after that it is important to make a break; otherwise it would go on checking if input equals "2" and so on.
the default branch is activated if nothing else matches. So your program would also write "You have exited the program" if your input was e.g. "r". If you don't want that, just add another case "x" and write your thing.